# How to add a extra value to the query in c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a query like this

```
var values = ProjectContext.controloptions.Where(i => i.id == id).Select(i => new {

          i.value
        }).ToList();
```

now the values contains 4 records i want to add 2 more records like

```
  values.Insert(0, new { "Select" });
  values.Add("AddNew");
```

But it is showing an error. Where `i.value` is the `varchar` field in the database.

How can I add the two records in to the list without extra field.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. They must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access

Answer (score 1):

you are selecting anonymous types. You can add another object of this type only by matching names of the properties and their types, like this:

```
var values = new[]{ new Options{value = 666, id = 5}} //array to demo purposes
                .Where(i => i.id == 5)
                .Select(i => new {
                              value = i.value.ToString()
                })
                .ToList();

values.Add(new {value = "Select"}); 
values.Insert(0, new {value = "AddNew"});
```

Now `values` contain three object of anonymous type (one property `value` of type `string`) and can be printed as

```
AddNew 
666 
Select
```

Consider creating new custom class and then using it in the `Select` projection, like this:

```
class MyCustomClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then create this object in `Select`

```
List<MyCustomClass> values = new[]{ new Options{value = 666, id = 5}}
                .Where(i => i.id == 5)
                .Select(i => new MyCustomClass {
                              Value = i.value.ToString()
                    })
                .ToList();

values.Add(new MyCustomClass { Value = "Select"});              
values.Insert(0, new MyCustomClass { Value = "AddNew"});
```

now your List is of named type `List<MyCustomClass>` and elements can be added and removed to it with named classes

Comment: I don't want to use custom variables like value or any other. Can't we directly add a value to list.

Comment: yes, as I've showed you in the first example - `values.Add(new {value = "Select"});` By *custom variables* you probably mean custom types